# Searching for a better Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control Tool. Migrating from StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, structuremap, autofac

***Why leaving StructureMap?***

As stated by **Jeremy Miller** (The guy behind StructureMap): [No Silverlight support](http://jeremydmiller.com/2012/01/11/kicking-off-structuremap-3/)

***Why I need Silverlight support?***

I'm starting to write **WindowsPhone** apps, so looks like I need this.

***Purpose of this question?***

I love **StructureMap**. It's full of **features** and I've been using it for many of my projects. **But I have to choose a new one**. Which one should I choose?

[**AutoFac?**](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

[**Ninject?**](http://www.ninject.org/)

Other tools?

***What I want from new framework?***

**Supporting Windows Phone.**

Right now I'm registering my singleton dependencies using **StructureMap** like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(Function(config)
config.For(Of TPlugin).Singleton.Use(Of TConcrete)())
```

Or this (for generic types):

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(Function(config)
config.For(Of GetType(IRepository(Of ))).Use(Of GetType(Repository(Of )))())
```

Or forwarding types:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(Sub(config) config.Forward(Of TResolveBy, TRequested)())
```

I want to do the same things with syntax near to StructureMap(**or a better syntax**)

***What I want from you?***

Do you have any experience with them?

Which one do you prefer?

Which one do you recommend to be used in a Windows Phone App?

Any other suggestions?

***Update:***

What about **life cycle** and **initializing of the concrete type**(using a function instead of just defining the type)?
In StructureMap :

```
config.For(pluginType).Singleton.Use(concreteType)
```

or

```
config.For(Of TPlugin).HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped.Use(SomeFunction)
```

Comment: Really? 1 down vote & 1 close request for this question? Can I ask why?

Comment: Probably because the question isn't technically answerable - it's opinion-based or subjective rather than objective. For example, if both Ninject and Autofac support Windows Phone, then which you choose is a matter of preference, not necessarily technical merit. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: I'm asking from fellow developers about an IoC container that can support Windows Phone and I'm asking from them about their experience with that tools. I found out about SimpleContainer because of Derek's answer. I learnt from Stripling about syntax of Ninect. If both of them supports WP7, I'll will not choose one of them based on my preference. Answers to this question will help me choose. So please grove up and STOP down voting every thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend Ninject. I use it for all my projects mainly because of its auto-binding feature, that allows you to put together interface and its implementation automatically without explicit configuration (like in your samples) - example can be found [here](http://frankmao.com/2011/03/22/ninject-auto-binding/).

And you can still use manual configuration just like in your code samples - check out Ninject documentation for examples.

It seems to [support Silverlight](http://www.timmykokke.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-mvvm-ninject-and-silverlight/) as well, so it should be usable for you.

EDIT:

As per StriplingWarrior's comment, the way auto-binding syntax works has changed in recent version of Ninject - check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868159/120955) for details.

Comment: +1. Just a quick note: the convention binding syntax has changed in Ninject 3. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9868159/120955

Comment: Warning: Silverlight != Silverlight for Windows Phone. There is a crucial part missing on the WP7 version of Silverlight, which is lightweight code generation (LCG), which is needed to compile Expression trees. Many containers use LCG or Expression trees to optimize code. So are you sure Ninject has a Silverlight version for Windows Phone as well?

Comment: @Steven I am. See http://www.ninject.org/download.html - there is WP7 version available.

Comment: Thanks a lot from both of you guys(Steven & Nikola)

Answer (score 1):

When I did some research a while back to decide what DI framework to use, I found that a lot of people seemed to favor Ninject. I've been using it ever since, and loving it. Remo Gloor has done some really great work with it and its various extensions, and we just upgraded to Ninject 3 a few days ago.

The binding syntax is pretty simple. I usually use a `NinjectModule` subclass and say (in C#):

```
Bind<TPlugin>().To<TConcrete>()
```

... which I believe is pretty similar to what you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SimpleContainer that's packaged with Caliburn Micro.
[IOC Battle–Revisited](http://buksbaum.us/2012/05/22/ioc-battlerevisited/)

Update: there is also a separate [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Container) package for SimpleContainer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Derek, nice link. +1 for SimpleContainer.

Comment: Maybe someone doesn't like SimpleContainer :)

Comment: I'm not sure disliking SimpleContainer would be a valid reason to vote this question down.

Comment: I don't think the question was voted down, I think @Afshin Gh  was referring to my answer, it was +1, then voted down.  I use Ninject as well, I like SimpleContainer for wp7 since it's built into Caliburn Micro.

Answer (score 0):

Who needs an IoC tool?  The Factory and Abstract Factory patterns are easy, awesome, and you never have to wonder if they support technology XYZ.

Comment: Lots of great open source applications out there are using IoC tools. I have nothing against Factory Pattern, but I find Repository & Unit of Work more interesting and I think using IoC is a better approach.

Comment: Factory and Abstract Factory patterns make it difficult to write self-contained unit tests, whereas DI makes it easy to use a mocking framework or fake implementations to set up the scenario you want to test. When done right, you don't have to worry about DI supporting a given technology, either. The vast majority of your code is completely agnostic of the IoC container you use.